# Determining constant values from 3 equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function

I have the following three equations:

$$\begin{align*}
k_1 + k_3 &= 0\\
k_1e^{k_2(0.1)} + k_3 &= 1\\
k_1e^{k_2(1)} + k_3 &= 100
\end{align*}$$

How do you go about solving for values $k_1$, $k_2$, and $k_3$?

Obviously $k_1$, $k_3$ are related in the fact one must be the negative of the other to make the first equation true. All that is given in lecture is "Mathematica determines the constants of these three equations to be...", it doesn't actually explain how to solve them yourself.

Thanks.

Comment: Yep, sorry about that.

Comment: Yes, the function is $f(x) = k_1e^{k_2(x)} + k_3$ where x ranges from 0 to 1.

Comment: so is the last equation written correctly?

Comment: Yes it is. Why do you think it isn't?

Comment: Because your last comment makes it look like there should be a plus sign between $k_1$ and the exponential in the last two equations.

Comment: My bad again. No plus sign.

Answer (score 3):

$k_3=-k_1$.

$k_1e^{(1/10)k_2}-k_1=1$ yields $k_1={1\over e^{(1/10)k_2}-1}$

$k_1e^{k_2}-k_1=100$ yields $k_1={100\over e^{k_2}-1}$

So we have $${1\over e^{(1/10)k_2}-1}={100\over e^{k_2}-1}$$ to solve for $k_2$.

$e^{k_2}-1=100(e^{(1/10)k_2}-1)$

Let $Q=e^{(1/10)k_2}$. Then $Q^{10}-1=100Q-100$, $Q^{10}-100Q+99=0$.

One solution of this equation is $Q=1$, which leads to $k_2=0$, which we must reject --- it slipped in when we divided by $e^{k_2}-1$.

That leaves a polynomial of degree $9$. There is in general no closed form formula for the solution of such an equation. Mathematica uses numerical methods, for example, the calculus-based Newton's Method.

Comment: In the book it gives the answers as 

$k_1 = 2.10999$
$k_2 = 3.87937$
$k_3 = -2.10999$

All these are said to be irrational numbers.

Comment: OK. Your point?

Comment: How were they gotten?

Comment: Presumably, by numerical methods, such as Newton's Method.